# Installation of Tizen tv app (.wgt) to customer device(tv) for testing before publishing

Tags: tizen-web-app

I have developed Samsung / Tizen tv (web app) and wanted to provide it to our customer, so they can install it on their tv and test it before publishing on Samsung Tv Seller office.
suppose customer is on remote location?
Thansk!

I tried by using usb drive, it can't work since it only shows Phots, video & music file not .wgt package file. I also tried by uploading package file on G drive and tried to direct download , unfortunately download not supports on Tizen tv.
I successfully installed only by using tizen Studio and Tv on same network Or by using abd command line tool for same network.

I don't want customer to have install tizen studio and do all the tech stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, for installing the wgt file you need sdb installed on PC connected to your TV.

As SDB doesn't have much dependencies, it is possible to not install a Tizen studio, but only provide to customer an 'installation package' which includes sdb binary itself (which should be matching customer's OS) and some script (bash or bat file), which will do all install work for a customer.

Answer (score 0):

The right workflow should be:

1. Apply for Partner Seller account.
2. There is a tool for Partner Seller account called USB Demo Packaging tool.

Check Q1 in this link:
https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/faq/application-installation.html

3. This tool allows you to create a ".tmg" package and a license file from the WGT file.
4. Share the generated files and your client can install the app via USB stick.

Hope this works!